# Unable to Select all checkboxes with Angular

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

Populated Angular dataTable and trying to select all checkboxes but unable to select, tried with below code. Could you please suggest me the solution. Please refer below Stackblitz for working demo

```js
isChecked = false;
checkuncheckall() {
    if (this.isChecked == true) {
        this.isChecked = false;
    } else {
        this.isChecked = true;
    }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-population?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I guess you'll have to iterate with a for loop over each element in your table. There is an example here: https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-check-uncheck-checkbox-list-with-indeterminate-state-using-matcheckboxmodule/

Answer (score 2):

Solved your problem. Forked at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-population-ody4qj?file=app/app.component.ts).

Changes:

1. Added all data selection at `checkuncheckall` function:

> ```
> if (this.persons && this.persons.length) {
>   this.persons.forEach(f => (f.check = this.isChecked == true));
> }
> ```

2. Remove checkbox from your table column settings:

> ```
> columns: [
>     { name: "" },
>     { data: "index" },
>     { title: "Dropdown" },
>     { title: "ExtraColumn" },
>     { data: "firstname" },
>     { data: "lastname" }
> ]
> ```